# Calculating Mahalanobis distance

Tags: linear-algebra, covariance, clustering, mahalanobis-distance

I am slightly confused as to how you calculate Mahalanobis distance given a set of data. I have tried asking my tutor for help but he does not seem interested in helping what so ever and I am continuously insulted. I thought I would turn to the community for help.

I have a set of data here and I have performed distance calculation once using Euclidean distance to group the data. Now I am looking to calculate distance using Mahalanobis distance. I have calculated the means and also calculated a Pooled covariance matrix. I am unsure as to what I need to do from here to begin calculating distances for each point.

Data clustered into 3 clusters after performing Euclidean distance to place points into initial groups
[image]

Pooled Covariance matrix
\begin{bmatrix}1.394&1.702\\1.702&6.62\end{bmatrix}

Inverse Pooled Covariance
\begin{bmatrix}1.046&-0.269\\-0.269&0.221\end{bmatrix}

Comment: This sounds like you might do better on Stats.SE.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:
$$d^2_{(1,1)}=\begin{bmatrix}1& 1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1.046&-0.269\\-0.269&0.221\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\ 1\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I am slightly confused, do I need to calculate a pooled covariance matrix for each Cluster? Also you mention 1,1 but would I not need to subtract the mean from the point: 1-2.7, 1-5.6?

Comment: Sorry, you are right. You need to subtract the mean from each point. And you need to do it for each cluster

Comment: Thanks for getting back. I wanted to make sure I was calculating my pooled covariance matrix correctly. For each cluster/group we calculate the Covariance matrix first. Then we use the amount of samples in each cluster e.g. cluster1 has 7 samples so we do 7/15 * Covariance Matrix to obtain the Pooled covariance matrix? Finally I would inverse the Pooled covariance matrix and use this to begin determining distances from points.

Comment: Seems reasonable to me. This seems to me like the same approach as https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2020/07/01/pooled-covariance-between-group.html